Make a POST request to Non controller method using AJAX in .NET 6
Below Ajax call is not invoking the Non controller method(Index) in .NET core 6.
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    url: form.action,
    data: formData,
    success: () => {
    },
    error: () => {   
    }});



Html :
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div>
    
    --------
    ----
    --
    </div>

    <div class="btns">
        <button class="fill reset-button" type="button">@Html.PropertyFor(model => model.ResetButtonText)</button>
        <button class="fill send-button" type="button" this.disabled="true">@Html.PropertyFor(model => model.SendButtonText)</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="se">
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="display:none">Sending...</div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">There was an issue with the submitted data. Please correct any errors and resubmit.</div>
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none">Your message was sent successfully.</div>
    </div>
</form>


Method :
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IViewComponentResult Index(Block currentContent, ViewModel viewModel)
    {
    //code
    }

Hardcoded the url , still it is not invoking the Index method .
Ajax call should invoke Index method which is not part of Controllers folder.

Is your project using asp.net core razorpage or mvc? Have you checked in the developer tools whether ajax successfully sent the request and related data? Is there any relevant error information in the developer tools?Is the Non controller method (Index) method you mentioned a method in a controller in a separate folder or in a razor page?

Where is that Index() method, why do you expect there to be a public endpoint for it? Also, how would the form data correspond to the arguments of the Index() method?

@YuningDuan, our project is using MVC. I have checked in developer tools , all the related data is being passed with request . There is no error information. I'm calling a method which is outside of Controllers.

@TedNyberg, As part of Optimizely upgrade we have moved some controllers to components. Now I'm calling the method which is part of one of the component. Data is being passed from Ajax call.

Is the Index method you provided in a class that inherits from a controller? Or is it inherited from the ViewComponent class?

it is inherited from ViewComponent class @YuningDuan

In .NET Core, ViewComponent is not accessed through traditional controller routing. It is usually called through the @Component.InvokeAsync method in the view or page View components.
If you want to submit to the corresponding URL endpoint using ajax, you can submit to a method inherited from controller, call the view component in it, pass currentContent and viewModel and return the result of the view component. Here is an example for your reference：
First, I configured a corresponding method in a controller to correspond to the ajax endpoint URL and data, and then called the component named home1 that I created:
Homecontroller:
public class HomeController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public IActionResult InvokeHome1Component(Block currentContent, ViewModel viewModel)
  {
      var result = ViewComponent("Home1", new { currentContent, viewModel });
      return result;
  }
}

Home1ViewComponent :
public class Home1ViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IViewComponentResult Invoke(Block currentContent, ViewModel viewModel)
    {
            
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}

I configured the relevant component view in the path Views\Home\Components\Home1\Default.cshtml :
@model ViewModel

<div>
    <h1>@Model.ResetButtonText</h1>
    <h1>@Model.SendButtonText</h1>
</div>

Ajax submits the corresponding URL endpoint. And  I configured the update page content in the success callback and presented it in <div id="viewComponentContainer"></div>:
@model ViewModel

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
       
    </div>

    <div class="btns">
        <button class="fill reset-button" type="button">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ResetButtonText)</button>
        <button class="fill send-button" type="submit">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SendButtonText)</button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="se">
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="display:none">Sending...</div>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none">There was an issue with the submitted data. Please correct any errors and resubmit.</div>
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="display: none">Your message was sent successfully.</div>
    </div>
</form>

<div id="viewComponentContainer"></div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('form').on('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var form = this;
                var formData = new FormData(form);
                formData.append('currentContent', 'exampleContent');
                formData.append('viewModel.ResetButtonText', 'Reset');
                formData.append('viewModel.SendButtonText', 'Send');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    url: '/Home/InvokeHome1Component',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#viewComponentContainer').html(response);
                        $('.alert-info').hide();
                        $('.alert-success').show();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $('.alert-info').hide();
                        $('.alert-danger').show();
                    },
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('.alert-info').show();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}

When I click the submit button, the data will first be submitted to my controller method:

and then passed to my view component:

Finally, the component update is completed and loaded in my view:

Update:
After my test, when the parameter name in the model is the same as the model parameter name received in the method, the data cannot be received in the controller, such as:
public class Block
{
     public int? Id { get; set; }
     public string? currentContent { get; set; }

}


This will cause the model binding to fail. Therefore, to avoid this error, you need to avoid encountering the same name, such as changing the parameter name in the model:
public class Block
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string? Content { get; set; }  
}

  public class ViewModel
  {
        
      public string? ResetButtonText { get; set; }
      public string? SendButtonText { get; set; }
  }

ajax:
formData.append('Content', 'exampleContent');
formData.append('viewModel.ResetButtonText', 'Reset');
formData.append('viewModel.SendButtonText', 'Send');

When passing data again



In Controller , currentContent is coming as null, but in Component it is having the data. Do we need to assign anything before the AJAX call.
I could see below code to pass currentContent(BlockContent)
formData.append('currentContent', 'exampleContent') but it is not that clear what data has to be passed here.

Can't we use either one of them Controller or Component to achieve whatever required. Is it advisable to use both of them for a simple GET , POST requests.

I updated the reason why the controller method cannot receive data in the update part. You can check if there is the same reason.  Can't we use either one of them Controller or Component to achieve whatever required. Can you describe what you want to achieve?

Is a single controller sufficient for handling both GET and POST requests, or is a view component also necessary? Alternatively, can a view component handle both GET and POST requests on its own, or is there a specific reason for using both controllers and view components?

View components cannot process requests directly because the parameters come directly from the call of the view component, not from model binding, so view components cannot handle GET and POST requests by themselves. For more information about view components, you can refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-8.0#view-component-methods.A single controller can handle GET and POST requests because it can participate in model binding and obtain info through http requests.

The reason why controllers and view components are used at the same time is that in .NET Core, ViewComponent cannot be directly accessed through traditional controller routing. If you want to use ajax to route to the endpoint method to call ViewComponent, you need to first obtain the data through the controller and then call the view component in it
